# How to Crawl .Swf(flash) files of a website for testing XSS?

Tags: flash

I would like to know if there's a possible way to crawl or find .swf files in a website? for example www.somesite.com/js/ZeroClipboard.swf

Let me know if there's a technique or a tool to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search will do -

**site:somesite.com ext:swf inurl:ZeroClipboard**